# Camera Capture Task in windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, isolatedstorage, cameracapturetask

I am working on windows phone application in which i need to store a captured image from the camera in isolated storage without saving it in the camera roll. I am able to store the captured image in the isolated storage but a copy of the captured image in also stored in the camera roll. Is there any way i can keep the image within the isolated storage rather than the camera roll.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to save to ONLY isolated storage, you cannot use the `CameraCaptureTask`. In WP8, it will transparently save a copy of the image to the camera roll, regardless of what you do.

That said, there is a solution. You'll need to use the camera APIs to basically create and use your own `CameraCaptureTask`. I'm not going to go into huge depth, but this should get you started.

First thing you need to do is follow [this tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh708750.aspx) to create the view and basic application. They use the `cam_CaptureImageAvailable` method to store the image to the camera roll. You'll want to modify that to store it in isolated storage like so:

```
using (e.ImageStream)
{
   using(IsolatedStorageFile storageFile = IsolatedStorageFile.GetuserStoreForApplication())
   {
      if( !sotrageFile.DirectoryExists(<imageDirectory>)
      {
         storageFile.CreateDirectory(<imageDirectory>);
      }

      using( IsolatedStorageFileStream targetStream = storageFile.OpenFile( <filename+path>, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
      {
         byte[] readBuffer = new byte[4096];
         int bytesRead;
         while( (bytesRead = e.ImageStream.Read( readBuffer, 0, readBuffer.Length)) > 0)
         {
            targetStream.Write(readBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
         }
      }
   }
}
```

From this point, you have a functional camera application that stores only to isolated storage. You may want to spice it up with color effects or something, but it's not necessary.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer above is not correct for Windows Phone 8 Silverlight 8.1

I used the Completed event to customize the code I want to be executed after the photo is taken and accepted.

```
    public MainPage()
    {

        InitializeComponent();

        cameraTask = new CameraCaptureTask();
        cameraTask.Completed += new EventHandler<PhotoResult>(cameraTask_Completed);
        cameraTask.Show();

    }

    void cameraTask_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e)
    {
        if (e.TaskResult != TaskResult.OK) 
            return;
            // Save picture as JPEG to isolated storage.
            using (IsolatedStorageFile isStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
            {
                using (IsolatedStorageFileStream targetStream = isStore.OpenFile(fileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
                {
                    // Initialize the buffer for 4KB disk pages.
                    byte[] readBuffer = new byte[4096];
                    int bytesRead = -1;

                    // Copy the image to isolated storage. 
                    while ((bytesRead = e.ImageStream.Read(readBuffer, 0, readBuffer.Length)) > 0)
                    {
                        targetStream.Write(readBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    }
                }
            }

    }
```

Resources
http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.tasks.cameracapturetask
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/CSWP8ImageFromIsolatedStora-8dcf8411